# Find Excel Cell values Instead of Formulas with Python

Tags: python, excel, data-science

I am trying to collect and parse data from an excel workbook with python. The workbook has four separate sheets, two of which I need to work with. The first sheet, "Enter Data Here,' is connected to the last sheet, "Calculations," where the formulas from "Calculations" depend on the data that was entered earlier. So, my first task is to enter data into "Enter Data Here:"

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Markov with Run Frequencies.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws['C2'] = 100
wb.save('C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Markov with Run Frequencies.xlsx')
```

Next, I need to go to the calculations page and pull numbers from there. I have tried using openpyxl and xldr packages (example shown), but for almost all the data, they return with empty or nan.

```py
import xldr
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:/Users/iijof/Desktop/Markov with Run Frequencies.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(3)
print(ws.cell(10,10))
```

I could be wrong, but I believe the reason that they return with empty or nan is because "Calculations'" inputs are on the separate sheet within that workbook. Is there a way, using one of the packages I tried or something else entirely, to get a return with the numeric value of the cell?

Here is the [link to download](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=329BE185EBB717AF%21111&authkey=%21AIta5krPwoulsDU&page=View) the excel file, if it helps.

Comment: For getting the output of the formula I prefer [the `xlwings` module](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html). The module can interface with things like `pandas` too.

Comment: use `data_only=True` in load_workbook in openpyxl